# How to make material ui Chips delete svg icon in white color using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using material UI component and I gave custom class to my chip

like you can see I have attached screenshot
[image]

here I am trying to make that cross button in white like this

[image]

So I check doing inspect element and came to know that it is SVG icon

so in `App.css`
I tried to make all the svg icon in white like this

`svg{ color:white }`

but still its not helping me still it showing me black color cross button

Comment: although ```!important``` could solve the issue, it is not recommended I think. In your ```Chip``` component, you could try using the ```sx``` property like this ```<Chip
  label="Custom delete icon"
  onClick={handleClick}
  onDelete={handleDelete}
  deleteIcon={<Your Icon Here   sx={{backgroundColor: 'your color'}} />}
  variant="outlined"
/>``` from https://mui.com/components/chips/#custom-delete-icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use !important like `svg{ color:white !important; }` and check if it works.

if it does not work then inspect the cross element and check what class is applied on it then using that class redeclare your styles in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

You should aim at `path` not `svg`.
So in your case it will be `svg path { background-color: #fff }`

Answer (score 0):

For React `@mui/icons-material/` icons you can create a className that sets the `path` color, as it's just an svg element.

```
import VideocamIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Videocam';

...
<VideocamIcon className={styles.videoCamIcon} />
```

```scss
.videoCamIcon {
  path { color: #fff };
}
```